# Does anything come of tickling the llamas?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

On the Loot screen, there is a button dedicated to tickling the llama piñatas.

[image: why does this exist]

When you do this, they will respond to it with different dialogue, with different types of llamas having their own lines.

Is this literally the only use for this feature, or is there a chance for something useful to come of doing this? For instance, does tickling a llama before smashing it have any effect on that piñata upgrading to silver or gold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how useful you'd consider this, but I repeatedly hit the R3 button to 'tickle' for 5 minutes finding nothing ever occurred other than the repeated laughs or voice lines.

I then saved up a 10 mini llamas and gave them all a range of tickles from 1 - 10 tickles in order. I got one silver llama, the 6th one, but to me this just indicates that **tickling llamas has no impact whatsoever and is purely for "fun"**.